# Youtube Video is not Playing on Both Tabs (Socket.io)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io, youtube-iframe-api

I'm trying to build a website where users can watch youtube videos together. I'm using node.js and socket.io for my server, and the YouTube iFrame API for my video player. However, when the user clicks the play button, the YouTube video does play, but only on the current tab and not on the other tabs. You can see this in action here, if you open 2 tabs side by side.

https://socketio-tests.stcollier.repl.co/

For some reason as well, I'm getting an error in the chrome dev tools:

[image]

**Does anyone know why when the user clicks the button, the video does not play for others, even though I'm emitting the events?**

Here's HTML/CSS/JS code:

```js
var socket;


function onload(){

  socket = io();

  const playButton = document.querySelector('.playButton');
  const pauseButton = document.querySelector('.pauseButton');

  playButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    socket.emit('play');
  })
  pauseButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    socket.emit('pause');
  })
  socket.on('play', () => {
    playVideo();
  });
  socket.on('pause', () => {
    pauseVideo();
  });
  function pauseVideo() {
    player.pauseVideo();
  }
  function playVideo() {
    player.playVideo();
  }

}

//
//YOUTUBE API STUFF
//

      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          playerVars: {
              'playsinline': 1,
              'autoplay': 0,
              'controls': 0,
          },
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        console.log(true)
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          //setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
```

```css
.pauseButton {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

.playButton {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <meta name="charset" charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onload()">

    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div><br>

    <button onclick="pauseVideo()" class="pauseButton">Pause</button>
    <button onclick="playVideo()" class="playButton">Play</button>

  </body>
</html>
```

And here's my server code:

```js
const http = require("http");
const express = require("express");
const socketio = require("socket.io");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();
const httpserver = http.Server(app);
const io = socketio(httpserver);

const gamedirectory = path.join(__dirname, "public");

app.use(express.static(gamedirectory));

httpserver.listen(3000);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('A user just connected.');
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('A user has disconnected.');
  });
  // This used to be right after the 'A user has disconnected.' log
  socket.on('buttonClicked', () => {
    console.log('received: buttonClicked');
    io.emit('buttonClicked');
  });
  socket.on('play', () => {
    console.log('received: play');
    io.emit('play');
  });
  socket.on('pause', () => {
    console.log('received: pause');
    io.emit('pause');
  });
});
```

Here's a link to the full code:

https://replit.com/@STCollier/Socketio-Tests?v=1 (open in a new tab)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

you have multiple variables called playX change the functions names as well as the queryselectors names

```js
function onload(){

  socket = io();

  const player= document.querySelector('.playButton');
  const pauser= document.querySelector('.pauseButton');
  
  function Fplayer() {
    player.pauseVideo();
  }
  function Fpauser() {
    player.playVideo();
  }
  
  player.addEventListener('click', () => {
    socket.emit('play');
  })
  pauser.addEventListener('click', () => {
    socket.emit('pause');
  })
  socket.on('play', () => {
    Fplayer();
  });
  socket.on('pause', () => {
    Fpauser();
  });

}
```